# Odd Behavior When Modifying Values In Table Using jQuery/For-Loop For Child Selection

Tags: jquery, html, css, loops, html-table

I am in the process of generating a numbered table on a website. This will eventually be a calendar I have developed from scratch. It starts as a table of height 6 and width 7. I am <strike>currently having</strike> attempting to have the code label the cells of this table 1-42, top-to-bottom, and left-to-right. The code for the table is as follows:

```
<table id="calendar">
    <thead>
        <tr class="cal_row">
            <th class="cal_col">Sun</td>
            <th class="cal_col">Mon</td>
            <th class="cal_col">Tue</td>
            <th class="cal_col">Wed</td>
            <th class="cal_col">Thr</td>
            <th class="cal_col">Fri</td>
            <th class="cal_col">Sat</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                   <tr class="cal_row">
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
        </tr>
                    <tr class="cal_row">
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
        </tr>
                    <tr class="cal_row">
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
        </tr>
                    <tr class="cal_row">
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
        </tr>
                    <tr class="cal_row">
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
        </tr>
                    <tr class="cal_row">
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
            <td class="cal_col">00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

-and the jQuery to do this is as follows:

```
function cal_bt(){
var $bt = $('#month_tag');
$bt.click(function(){
    var child_index;
    var child_row;
    for( var i = 0 ; i < 42 ; i++ ){
        child_index = ( i % 7 ) + 1;
        child_row = ( Math.floor( i / 6 ) ) + 1;
        $('#calendar > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + child_row + ') > .cal_col:nth-child(' + child_index +')').html(i + 1);
    }
});
}
```

Right now, it is doing something a bit odd. The table comes out looking like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/ivwA5CW]

I'm not quite sure what is going on.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please include the `HTML` code that `#month_tag` references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Math.floor(i / 7)`, not `Math.floor(i / 6)`

[**jsFiddle example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7yAZ9/1/)

---

A more compact alternative could be to use:

```
$("#example").click(function(){
  $("tbody .cal_col").each(function(i){
     $(this).text(i + 1);
  });
});
```

Where `#example` is the ID of the button you wish to trigger the event with.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7yAZ9/4/)

Comment: Oh. Wow. I have been looking at code way too long today. I guess I just needed a spare pair of eyes. You're the best!

Comment: @user3451400 No worries, here's a quicker alternative solution - http://jsfiddle.net/7yAZ9/4/.